# form binding not working get request

Tags: php, forms, symfony, silex

Here is my symfony form

```
class TeradataType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
     $builder
       ->add('emplId','text',array(
        'attr'=>array(
            'class'=>'filter-control'
                )
       ))
       ->add('tmMbrUid','text',array(
        'attr'=>array(
            'class'=>'filter-control'
                )
       ))
       ->add('fstNm','text',array(
        'attr'=>array(
            'class'=>'filter-control'
                )
       ))
       ->add('lstNm','text',array(
            'attr'=>array(
                'class'=>'filter-control'
                )
       ));


}
public function getName(){
    return '';
   }

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ));
}
}
```

Here is how i am printing my initial form:

```
 {{ form_start(form, {'action':path('teradataResult'),'method':'GET','attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate','id':'form','class':'form-horizontal'}}) }}
                        {{ form_widget(form) }}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Here is my controller class:

```
 $form= $app['form.factory']    ->createBuilder(TeradataType::class)
                                    ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        var_dump($form->getData());
    }
```

when I use POST request to submit the form, i get the form data and form binding works but when I use GET request, i dont get any form data. How to fix this?

update:
I replaced this line of code:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

with

```
$form->submit($request);
```

and it works for the get request as well. But as per the documentation $form->submit($request) is deprecated and will be removed in symfony 3 (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html#passing-a-request-to-form-submit-deprecated)

Comment: Try adding `->setMethod('GET')` when calling createBuilder()

Comment: isValid only works on POST requests (or more accurately on submitted forms).  handleRequest does map GET data so $form->getData will work as expected for GET requests.  You can also use getErrors to validate GET requests.  Best way to understand what is happening is to check the Form.php source code.

Comment: Unrelated - but you don't want to return an empty string for the `getName()` function in your form definition - you could do something like `return 'teradata';` instead

Comment: @pavlovich it worked. you could post that as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @pradip glad it works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `setMethod('GET')` when calling `createBuilder()`. This should fix the problem:

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(TeradataType::class)
    ->setMethod('GET')
    ->getForm();
```